# Django TemplateSyntaxError: Template library bootstrap3 not found

Tags: django, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm quite the newbie at this, I installed django-bootstrap3. v5.3.1
added "bootstrap3" to the INSTALLED_APPS parameter in my settings file,
and started quoting {% load bootstrap3 %} in my template. I have also restarted django. However, im getting the error: Does anyone know how i might fix this?

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /jhgi/signup/

'bootstrap3' is not a valid tag library: Template library bootstrap3 not found, tried django.templatetags.bootstrap3,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.bootstrap3,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.bootstrap3,django_extensions.templatetags.bootstrap3

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/jhgi/signup/
Django Version:     1.7.7
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

'bootstrap3' is not a valid tag library: Template library bootstrap3 not found, tried django.templatetags.bootstrap3,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.bootstrap3,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.bootstrap3,django_extensions.templatetags.bootstrap3

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1119
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
Python Version:     3.4.2
Python Path:    

['/Users/XXXX/PycharmProjects/XXXX',
 '/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev',
 '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Companion',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/extensions']

Server time:    Sun, 12 Apr 2015 20:47:32 +0000

Error during template rendering

In template /Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/Companion/templates/signup.html, error at line 5
'bootstrap3' is not a valid tag library: Template library bootstrap3 not found, tried django.templatetags.bootstrap3,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.bootstrap3,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.bootstrap3,django_extensions.templatetags.bootstrap3
```

Comment: Are you sure it's added to your INSTALLED_APPS? Because the template libraries Django is trying don't seem to include bootstrap3's.

Comment: Hi yes, I've tried to restart, and bootstrap3 is included in the INSTALLED_APPS parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Please recheck "bootstrap3" in your INSTALLED_APPS and restart django. New template tags will be added only after restart.

Comment: Rechecking doesn't help if bootstrap3 is already in INSTALLED_APPS and the server already restarted as the OP said.  The DEBUG=True error page dumps all sorts of information including Settings, so bootstrap3 is easily verified.   His problem is likely somewhere else, as mine was.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was filesystem permissions.

I'm running as a normal user on CentOS 7, but Apache runs in daemon mode as user:apache group:apache.   After doing a `pip install bootstrap3`, I forgot to do a `sudo chown -R :apache /srv/python`, where `/srv/python/.../site-packages` is on the python-path configured in WSGIDaemonProcess.  Making the newly-loaded site-package readable by group :apache and restarting httpd fixed the problem.